# Как правильно записать условие с неравенством?

Tags: php

Написал условие с неравенством, но оно выдает с ошибкой.

```
if (1 < 100 > 99) { //1 меньше 100, но больше 99
    $x = substr($koluser[0], 0, 2);
} elseif (1 > 10 < 99) { //1 больше 10, но меньше 99
    $x = substr($koluser[0], 0, 1);
} elseif (1 < 10) { //1 меньше 10
    $x = '1';
}
```

Может, неправильно записал, но надо, чтобы был такой смысл (записано в //).

Comment: интересно, а где вы такой синтаксис php нашли? if (1 < 100 > 99)

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php так писать нельзя. Если нужно, то пишите так:

```
(1 < 100) && (100 > 99)
```

Comment: нужно подучить дискретную математику автору